# Repository pattern php - is interface needed?

Tags: php, repository-pattern

I have the following code and I don't know how to use the interface, I feel like I don't need it but I want to
I am using  only composer for autoloading without any framework

service code (run from batch file from the example)

```
try {
    $test = new testClass();  //how do I put here the interface , i dont want to put it here
    $test->run();

}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo  $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    die;
}
```

Test Class:

```
class TestClass extends AbstractClass
{
    private $_repo;

    public function __construct(RepositoryInterface $repo)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_repo =       $repo;
    }


    public function run(){

    }
```

AbstractClass

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{

    protected $logger;

    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        Configuration::config();
        $this->db =  PDOConnection::dbConnect();

    }
```

it is not working,  now I just call to the testRepository that implement the interface directly, without calling to the interface

so how can I register the interface to the constructor or I have to call it each place I initiate a testclass object

thanks

Comment: Please show code of `AbstractClass`

Comment: @J.Litvak updated but how its help ?

Comment: So where is the class that implements the `RepositoryInterface`? You'd need something like `$test = new Testclass(new TestRepo());`

Answer (score 0):

In your `TestClass` method construct need one argument.

```
public function __construct(RepositoryInterface $repo)
```

When you create object of class you did not use any arguments:

```
$test = new testClass();
```

Then add argument in `new testClass($repo);` or change `__construct` method like

```
public function __construct(RepositoryInterface $repo = null)
```

Comment: @Guz in your code `testClass();` is the same `testClass(null);` . Or you show not your real code?

Comment: I call like : $test = new testClass()
$test->run();
in my run function in test i call to 
$this->_repo->findAll();  but its null 
because the initiantion of null in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some understanding. @J.Litvak's answer does not provide this info either.

```
class TestClass extends AbstractClass
{
    private $_repo;

    public function __construct(RepositoryInterface $repo)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_repo =       $repo;
    }
}
```

This class has a constructor which requires an object which implements the `RepositoryInterface`.

As such, the variable you pass must be an object, and it must have used that `Interface`. With me so far?

This means that the following code is incorrect.

```
try {
    $test = new testClass(); 
    $test->run();
} catch(\Exception $e) { ... }
```

The line initializing the `$test` variable with an instance of `TestClass`, must an object which uses the `RepositoryInterface` for the `TestClass::__construct` function.

So, somewhere, you must create or have:

```
class CustomRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    public function findAll() { ... }
}
```

Now, update your `try{} / catch () {}` to the following:

```
$customRepository = new CustomerRepository();

try {
    $test = new testClass($customRepository); 
    $test->run();
} catch(\Exception $e) { ... }
```

Which should work, as the `CustomRepository` class `implements` the `interface` you require in the `TestClass::__construct` parameters.

Have a look at some of the PHP docs:

- [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)
- [constructors and destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with PHP DI module  and inject it via composer

something like :

```
return [
    // Bind an interface to an implementation
    RepositoryInterface::class => object(Repository::class),

];
```